# How requestdispatcher will work for rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, requestdispatcher

In servlet we can use requestdispatcher and it will forward from servlet to servlet or html file.but i tried this requestdispatcher in rest service.its not forwarding from service 1 to service 2.its just stop in service 1 not forwarding. i'm getting 404 error in client side.so how i can achieve this in rest service.following the code

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/v1/status1/toreply1"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

anything wrong in my coding..?please correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

404 means there is something wrong with URL "/v1/status1/toreply1", make sure it is correct

Comment: if i'm giving full url like http://localhost:8080/com.youtube.rest/api/v1/status1/toreply1.its giving error like url should start with '/'